# How to choose python version run when typing only "python" at prompt?

Tags: python, linux

I have just installed Python2.6 on a Red Hat linux server which was supplied with python2.4 preinstaleld.
When I type python, python2.4 is launched, typing python2.6 launches python 2.6 correctly.
What is the correct way to make 2.6 the default? Also how can this result be possible:

```
$ python -V && which python && pwd && ./python -V
Python 2.4.3
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin
Python 2.6.6
```

Comment: depends on your distribution. please update your question with that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a symlink actually.

```
$ ls -al `which python`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2010-04-21 12:08 /usr/bin/python -> python2.6
```

So changing the default version from 2.4 to 2.6 would be just:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -sf `which python2.6` python
```

Comment: This solves it, but I still don't get how the conflicting results from running python -V are possible.

Comment: `./python` runs it from the directory you're in, while `python` searches `$PATH`

Comment: He did run `which` to check what version was in PATH; however, which is an external command (try `type which`) and cannot see aliases. There was likely an alias, or `python` was hashed before a second copy was placed in /usr/local; `hash -r` flushes that.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and quickest way, is to prepend the path to the 2.6.6 version to your PATH variable for your shell. This would go into your `.bashrc` or `.profile`, etc.

Assuming this path is `/opt/foo/bin` it would be:

```
export PATH=/opt/foo/bin:$PATH
```

If you don't include the possible side effects of things in the new path, this is the quick win.

This really depends on if you need this to be system-wide.